Searching one document at a time from a vector store
In the context of my project, i'm making a chatbot that gives instructions to the user about the cv he uploaded (what to modify, what to add ...).
My current solution uses langchain since i want to maintain a conversation with openAI model (gpt-3.5). I also want to maintain context so that each user can come back and continue any conversation he had. For that purpose, i'm using OpenAI embeddings and MongoDB as a vectorstore in order to override gpt token limitation and not pass the CV each time in the prompt.
My biggest problem is that the vector store search is being made on all the existing data and not on a single specific CV of my choosing.
Here is my current code:
loader = TextLoader("data/data.txt")
documents = loader.load()
collection = db['vectors']
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectorstore = MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch(
    collection=collection,
    embedding=embedding,
)

vectorstore.add_documents(documents)

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
)

def chat_with_chain():
    chat_history = []
    while True:
        query = input("Prompt: ")
        if query.lower() in ['quit', 'q', 'exit']:
            break
        result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
        print(result['answer'])
        chat_history.append((query, result['answer']))

